# Proper way to use a trap to exit a shell-script in ZSH?

Tags: shell, command-line, scripting, zsh

I'm having trouble getting a trap function in a Zshell-script to work without exiting the shell. I have a simple countdown timer that I want to be able to interrupt using ^C, and when I do I want the trap to change the cursor status in the terminal.

My syntax is:

#!/bin/zsh

```
trap 'tput cnorm; exit' INT TERM
```

I've also tried:

```
trap 'tput cnorm; kill -9 $$' INT TERM
```

Both interrupts exit the shell entirely. How do I only exit the script  and return to the command line?

Any guidance will be most appreciated!

Comment: Are you sourcing the script or executing it in a separate process?

Comment: I'm sourcing it while I'm making changes, but once it works, itll be autoloaded as a function to be used in an interactive shell.

Comment: Did you tried to catch on `EXIT` signal?

Comment: How do I catch on exit? What do you mean? It works as an executable, but I want to autoload it into my environment as a function. None of my other function scripts are executable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Handling Signals With Trap

```sh
TRAPINT() {
    echo "TRAPINT() called: ^C was pressed"
}

TRAPQUIT() {
    echo "TRAPQUIT() called: ^\\ was pressed"
}

TRAPTERM() {
    echo "TRAPTERM() called: a 'kill' command was aimed at this program's process ID"
}

TRAPEXIT() {
    echo "TRAPEXIT() called: happens at the end of the script no matter what"
}

for i in {1..9}; do
    echo ${i}
    sleep 1
done
```

For all of these `TRAP[NAL]()` functions, if the final command is `return 0` (or if there is no return statement at all, then code execution will continue where the program left off, as if the signal was accepted, caught, and handled. If the return status of this function is non-zero, then the return status of the trap is retained, and the command execution that was previously taking place will be interrupted. You can do `return $((128+$1))` to return the same status as if the signal had not been trapped

As to why your shell is getting killed, it's because calling `kill -9 $$` will send the the signal 9 to the process ID associated with your shell. Signal #9, or `SIGKILL` is the one signal that can't be handled with traps. It's sort of a "kill of last resort" if a program truly needs to stop immediately, with no cleanup permitted.

Comment: Ah! That's the issue! I get it now. I've switched to the TRAPINT with a non zero return value and it works as expected! Thanks!!