# How can I keybind Ctrl-C to vi-kill-line only when in viins mode?

Tags: zsh, zsh-zle

What I want to achieve is to bind Ctrl-C to clearing the line without issuing a newline (*à la* ipython) *only* when editing the command line, while keeping Ctrl-C as the interrupt signal triggerer when a command is running. I'm using `bindkey -v`, ie vi-mode line editing, but I believe it's not relevant.

As a side note, I wish this feature will not create situations where Ctrl-C would not interrupt a running command.

I'm digging into this on my spare time, so I'll be interested in any clues. If I find something robust enough I'll post it as an answer indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any function named `TRAPINT` inside your .zshrc will trap interrupt signals sent by Ctrl-C. Inside there, you will want to test if you are in insert mode, which can be achieved by testing the `${KEYMAP}` variable. If it isn't, you should pass the return value of the parent process (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59925138/11305897) for a hint on this). This leads us to the following snippet :

```
TRAPINT() { 
    if [[ "${KEYMAP}" = "viins" -o "${KEYMAP}" = "main" ]]; then
        zle kill-whole-line
        zle reset-prompt
    else
        return ${128+$1}
    fi
}
```

This will work if you use vi-mode line editing. It should also catch emacs-mode, where `KEYMAP` should be set to `main`, although I did not test this specific use case. `zle reset-prompt` is *sometimes* needed to update the display.